# VS13 C++ greedy match not greedy enough

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio-2013

Consider the following code:

```
wstring String = L"HMM";
wsmatch Matches; 
if( regex_match( String, Matches, wregex( L"(H+|M+)([^HM]*)(H+|M+)([^HM]*)(H+|M+)" ) ) )
    wcout << Matches[1].str() << L"-" << Matches[3].str() << L"-" << Matches[5].str() << endl;
else
    wcout << L"No match\n";
```

You would expect that the second `M+` would greedily consume all M's and give us a `No match` as result. Instead we get `H-M-M` as result.

It looks that VS13 tries to maximise the number of submatches and sacrifices the greediness for that?

Comment: You get 1 match here: https://regex101.com/

Comment: @NathanOliver I'd like to see a saved instance of what you did. It gives me 1 match with 3 groups filled just like it was explained.

Comment: @melwil Had to take a screenshot.  I got this: http://i284.photobucket.com/albums/ll13/nathanoliver60097/regex_zpsukorvyit.png

Comment: Well, that is what OP is getting, observe closer and you see each char is in its own group. That behaviour would produce `H-M-M` in that code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You would expect that the second `M+` would greedily consume all `M`'s and give us a `No match` as result.

The behavior you're describing is *[possessive](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)*, not greedy.  A greedy quantifier consumes as much as it can originally, but then gives back as much as necessary to achieve an overall match.

In flavors that support them, possessive quantifiers are formed by adding a `+` after the normal quantifier.  This regex would behave the way you expect:

```
(H++|M++)([^HM]*+)(H++|M++)([^HM]*+)(H++|M++)
```

However, the flavor you're using doesn't support possessive quantifiers.  [Atomic groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) can be used for the same thing, but you don't have those either.

Answer (score 2):

`+`means one or more, and you have three groups that demand one or more H's and M's, which is why you get one of them in each group.

```
(H+|M+)  # Would like to match H
([^HM]*) # Accepted since you allow 0 occurrences
(H+|M+)  # Would like to match MM, but can only M
([^HM]*) #
(H+|M+)  # This NEEDS to match the last H or M
```

Greediness means it will match as much as possible, but it will never sacrifice a match for greediness.

Comment: But what then with `HMMM` as string, there is more than 1 way to match: `H-M-MM` and `H-MM-M`. There is no way to know which of the two will return and this makes it unusable!

Comment: It will return `H-MM-M`, the first greedy part will take as much as it can, then leave enough for the regex to still make a match.

Answer (score 1):

There are 5 capturing groups in your regex. All of them contain greedy patterns. That means no characters will be given away to the neighboring groups.

- `(H+|M+)` - Greedily matches Hs or Ms, but *only until the next character other than H or M or empty space*. Why empty space is included? Because....
- `([^HM]*)` - matches empty string or non-H or non-M greedily.
- `(H+|M+)` - Again, greedily matches 1 or more Hs or Ms until an empty string or non-H or non-M
- `([^HM]*)` - same as above
- `(H+|M+)` - same as above.

On regex101.com, empty strings captured  are in *non-participating groups*, you can turn them on in the site options.

You can also check how your regex behaves on http://regexstorm.net/tester. On Tables tab, you will always see all captured substrings.

Comment: Same comment as to _melwil_.

Comment: With `HMMM`, you have the same behavior. The regex engine processes the pattern from left to right. The third subpattern `(H+|M+)` reads all `M`s possible reaching the end of string. Then it backtracks ONLY to match the empty space for Group 4 and one `M` so that the pattern requirements are met for the match to occur. If you do not want the 3rd group to have any `M`s, you could use a `*` quantifier with the last subpattern.

Comment: (it is hard for me to provide visual proofs since I'm on a mobile and the main regex testing services don't support mobile devices well. regex101.com freezes, regexr.com does not work, regexstorm.net does not let me copy and paste the generated link.)

Comment: Since possessive quantifiers nor atomic groups are available, you can use the `(H+|M+)([^HM]*)(H+|M+)([^HM]*)(H*|M*)`pattern and check if the last submatch is empty. If it is, you can return false.